# Apply filter on multi dimensional array and return filtered data along with parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, ecmascript-6

I have multidimensional array as provided on the code snippet , i want to filter that array with the value of innermost array and then return that value along with parent .
For example

From

```
const nodes = [
    {
        value: 'Documents',
        label: 'Documents',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
                label: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
            },
            {
                value: 'Expense Report.pdf',
                label: 'Expense Report.pdf',
            },
            {
                value: 'notes.txt',
                label: 'notes.txt',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: 'Photos',
        label: 'Photos',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'nyan-cat.gif',
                label: 'nyan-cat.gif',
            },
            {
                value: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',
                label: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',

            },
        ],
    },
];
```

If i filter by "notes.txt" it should yield

```
 [
    {
        value: 'Documents',
        label: 'Documents',
        children: [

            {
                value: 'notes.txt',
                label: 'notes.txt',
            }
        ]
]
```

This is what I tried but it just return the innermost filtered content

```js
const nodes = [
    {
        value: 'Documents',
        label: 'Documents',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
                label: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
            },
            {
                value: 'Expense Report.pdf',
                label: 'Expense Report.pdf',
            },
            {
                value: 'notes.txt',
                label: 'notes.txt',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: 'Photos',
        label: 'Photos',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'nyan-cat.gif',
                label: 'nyan-cat.gif',
            },
            {
                value: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',
                label: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',
               
            },
        ],
    },
];
let key="notes.txt";
//let filtered=nodes.filter(n=>n.value===key);
let cfiltered=nodes.map(n=>n.children.filter(n1=>n1.value===key));
//console.log(filtered);
console.log(cfiltered);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `map` over all the `parent` and filter out the unmatching children, then filter the intermediate result based on `children` size.

```js
const nodes = [{
    value: 'Documents',
    label: 'Documents',
    children: [{
        value: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
        label: 'Employee Evaluations.zip',
      },
      {
        value: 'Expense Report.pdf',
        label: 'Expense Report.pdf',
      },
      {
        value: 'notes.txt',
        label: 'notes.txt',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: 'Photos',
    label: 'Photos',
    children: [{
        value: 'nyan-cat.gif',
        label: 'nyan-cat.gif',
      },
      {
        value: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',
        label: 'SpaceX Falcon9 liftoff.jpg',

      },
    ],
  },
];
let key="notes.txt";
const result = nodes.map(node => ({ ...node,
  children: node.children.filter(child => child.value === key)
})).filter(node => node.children.length);
console.log(result);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Purely on the top of my head not tested but the idea would be:

- filter the nodes with at least one child.value == key
- filter the children of each resulting nodes:

It would go like this:

```
nodes.filter(n => n.children.reduce((cur, acc) => acc || cur.value == key, false).length > 0)
     .map(n => Object.assign(n, { children: n.children.filter(c => c.value == key }))
```

Maybe?

[Edit] added an initial value to reduce

[Edit] added the Object.assign so you get the original object too. I really should test it first ;) but you get the jist!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you probably could have higher dimensions than two. You want to treat this as a tree problem. Since you care about the parent and the child you can use a depth-first search.

```
function getNodeWithChild( accumulator, rootNode, searchValue ) {
  if (!rootNode || !rootNode.children) return accumulator;

  let parentNode;
  rootNode.children.forEach( child => {
     accumulator = getNodeWithChild(accumulator, child, searchValue);
     if (child.value === searchValue || child.label === searchValue) {
       if (parentNode) {
          parentNode.children.push(child);
       } else {
         parentNode = Object.assign({}, rootNode);
         parentNode.children = [child];
       }
    }
    if (parentNode) {
      accumulator.push(parentNode);
    }
  }
  return accumulator
} 

// And you call it like this:
const tree = { children: nodes } // just to simplify treat it like the same node as the rest
const filteredNodes = getNodeWithChild( [], rootNode, 'notes.txt');
```

This is a recursive version but can be made iterative with a queue. It is untested, could probably use some debugging. But it should return the parentNode of each child with the value. If both a parent and a child contain the value it will return both side by side. It will remove all children that don't have the value as well.